# Issue importing object within the same directory

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

Let's assume I have this  directory structure:

```
tumblelog/
  __init__.py
  manage.py
```

When I try to import app from `__init__.py` in `manage.py` with this statement:

```
from tumblelog import app
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named tumblelog
```

Comment: You are probably getting a circular import. Do you import from `manage.py` inside `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 2):

you will have to import from the module not the directory.

your code has to be:

```
from __init__ import app
```

this will create a pyc file.
the "from" expression declares that file, the "import" declares the function being imported.

alternatively, if you want to import all functions you could write

```
import __init__
```

and then write

```
__init__.app()
```

to use it

or import everything without having to retype the module all the time:

```
from __init__ import *
```

Comment: What if I had `models` file in the same directory under tumblelog and I wanted to import it in python interpreter? I get the same error when I use `from tumblelog.models import *`

Comment: If it is models.py, you should be able to call it with `import models` or `from  models import *`